# The movement of water and mercury drops

Tags: fluid-dynamics

A water drop and a mercury drop is taken inside identical conical glass pipes.Then which of the two drops tend to move more towards the narrow end than the other.

The orientation of the pipes are horizontal. And both the drops are of the same size.

since water forms concave meniscus and to account for the pressure difference of $ 2T/R$ where T is the surface tension and R radius of the meniscus the drop will rise.But I couldn't get for which of the two drops the effect will be more pronounced. Thanks.